# Search a string and return found words

Tags: javascript, search

I want to search the string for words found in the array books and return the words found. I have removed special characters. But I can not figure out how to search the string.  The search  returns -1

```
       <script>
var books = ['Genesis', 'Exodus', 'Leviticus', 'Numbers', 'Deuteronomy', 'Joshua', 'Judges'
, 'Ruth', 'Samuel', 'Samuel', 'Kings', 'Kings', 'Chronicles', 'Chronicles', 'Ezra', 'Nehemiah',
'Esther', 'Job', 'Psalms', 'Proverbs', 'Ecclesiastes', 'Song of Solomon', 'Isaiah', 'Jeremiah',
'Lamentations', 'Ezekiel', 'Daniel', 'Hosea', 'Joel', 'Amos', 'Obadiah', 'Jonah', 'Micah',
'Nahum', 'Habakkuk', 'Zephaniah', 'Haggai', 'Zechariah', 'Malachi', 'Matthew',
'Mark', 'Luke', 'John', 'Acts', 'Romans', 'Corinthians', 'Galatians', 'Ephesians', 'Philippians',
'Colossians', 'Thessalonians', 'Timothy', 'Timothy', 'Titus', 'Philemon', 'Hebrews', 'James',
'Peter', 'Peter', 'John', 'Jude', 'Revelation'];



var puzzle = 'Can you find the names of 25 books of the Bible in this paragraph? This is a most remarkable puzzle.\
 Someone found it in the seat pocket on a flight from Los Angeles to Honolulu, keeping himself occupied for hours.\
  One man from Illinois worked on this while fishing from his john boat. Roy Clark studied it while playing his banjo. \
  Elaine Victs mentioned it in her column once. One woman judges the job to be so involving, she brews a cup of tea to \
  help calm her nerves. There will be some names that are really easy to spot that’s a fact. Some people will soon find \
  themselves in a jam, especially since the book names are not necessarily capitalized. The truth is, from answers\
  we get, we are forced to admit it usually takes a minister or scholar to see some of them at the worst. \
  Something in our genes is responsible for the difficulty we have. Those able to find all of them will hear \
  great lamentations from those who have to be shown. One revelation may help, books like! Timothy and Samuel \
  may occur without their numbers. And punctuation or spaces in the middle are normal. \
  A chipper attitude will help you compete. Remember, there are 25 books of the Bible lurking \
 somewhere in this paragraph. Greater love hath no man than this, that a man lay down his life for his friends. John 15:13.';
// Remove punctuation and spaces and set to lowercase

var matcher = /[a-z]+/gi;
var matches = puzzle.match(matcher);
var result = matches.join('');
var results = result.toLowerCase();
books = books.map(function (e) {
    return e.toLowerCase();
  });

//Search results for books and return those found
var i;
for (i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
  var found =  puzzle.search(books)
  console.log(found);
}
      </script>
```

Comment: "Find all words in the array that are also in the string"

Comment: search the string "puzzle" looking for  words from the array "books"

Comment: if you read the string you will see what I am trying to do.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since it is a little bit a puzzle, here is the algorithm how to solve it:

1. In `puzzle` string you should remove all characters except letters.
2. In `puzzle` string move all letters to lowercase.
3. Move all books in `books` array to lowercase too.
4. For every element from `books` array you should use `puzzle.search(book)`. If the result is non-negative this book is in text.
5. Collect all books which had non-negative result to new array.

Last two steps can be done using `for` loop or using `reduce` method for `books` array. Below is the example, how it can be done:

```
puzzle = puzzle.replace(/\W/g,'').toLowerCase();

let result = [];

for(let i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
  const index = puzzle.search(books[i].toLowerCase());
  if(index >= 0 && result.indexOf(books[i]) == -1) {
    result.push(books[i]);
  }
}

console.log(result);
console.log(result.length);
```

Comment: ok I may have a little trouble with 4 and 5 but I will repost when I have it updated

Comment: @user163169 I've just added possible solution to my answer, check it

Comment: Fixed it a bit to get a right answer since some names in `books` array were duplicated

Comment: it only finds 9 books. it's very puzzling. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Fixed the code one more time. I've just checked, it returns exactly 25 books

Answer (score 0):

```
let reg = new RegExp('(' + books.join('|') + ')', 'gi');
let answer = puzzle.replace(/[^\w]/g,'').match(reg);
console.log(answer);
```

If you use this code right after you declare `puzzle` it should work.

You could do loops and maps and all that or you could use a regular expression to get the answer.

I've only tested this in a Chrome developer tools window but it should work wherever it's run.

The first line builds a regular expression object that is case insensitive and will search the entire string it is used on. If you did `console.log(reg)` it would look something like this `/(book1|book2|book3|...)/gi`.

The second line takes `puzzle`, removes all non-word characters (`puzzle.replace(/[^\w]/g,'')`), then matches against the regular expression that was built on line 1 (`.match(reg)`).

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
var matcher = books.join('|');
var matches = puzzle.match(matcher);
var result = matches.join(' ');
console.log(result);
```

Comment: it only finds Timothy there are 24 more words to be found